# Fragment is not being replaced after click in navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I tried every way to solve this problem but still I am not getting whats wrong with this code. Can you help me?

My mainpage activity is as

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainPage extends AppCompatActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private NavigationView mNavigationView;
private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransction;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

        Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mNavigationView=findViewById(R.id.idnav_view);
        ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        mDrawerLayout=findViewById(R.id.iddrawer_layout);


        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                  Fragment frag=null;
                  int itemId=menuItem.getItemId();

                if(itemId==R.id.id_nvHome){
                    frag=new HomeFragment();
                    }

                    else if(itemId==R.id.id_nvSearch){
                   frag=new SearchFragment();

                   }

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),menuItem.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if(frag!=null){
                    FragmentTransaction transction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transction.replace(R.id.idcontent_frame,frag);
                    transction.commit();
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    return true;
                }


                return false;



            }
        });

    }





    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

and for mypage activity layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Use DrawerLayout as root container for activity -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/iddrawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Layout to contain contents of main body of screen (drawer will slide over this) -->
    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/idcontent_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

    <!-- Container for contents of drawer - use NavigationView to make configuration easier -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/idnav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

my homefragment is as

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;



public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
        return v;

    }
}
```

and also layout for that is as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
       android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I want to **REPLACE FRAGMENT WITH OTHER FRAGMENT WHEN I CLICK ON NAVIGATION DRAWER ITEMS**

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Temporarily remove the `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>` from your layout, and test again.

Comment: It crashes after removing android.support.v7.widget.toolbar

Comment: Oh, sorry, I neglected to mention that you'd have to comment out the code for the `Toolbar`, too. Anyway, I'm thinking that your `Fragment` might be changing, but you just can't see it. Last I checked, `DrawerLayout` lays out any non-drawer child to `match_parent` in both directions, regardless of the width and height you've set. You have your `<Toolbar>` as a direct child of `DrawerLayout`, so it's filling the `DrawerLayout`, and covering the content `FrameLayout`, and the `Fragment`.

Comment: Actually, don't bother commenting any code. Just move the `<Toolbar>` into the `<FrameLayout>`.

Comment: You could put some breakpoints in your `Fragment` class and check if it is created or not.

Comment: I already commented this code   Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                                        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: I am getting name of fragment using gettitle

Comment: "I already commented this code Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar); setSupportActionBar(toolbar);" – That's not all of it. The `ActionBar` lines are using the `Toolbar`, as well, since you've set it as the support `ActionBar`.

Comment: Ok this solved problem. You are a genius but here is another problem I have https://ibb.co/j2rzkq the hello blank fragment is overflapping as shown in image

Comment: Yeah, that was just a quick test to check. `FrameLayout` stacks its child `View`s on top of each other, which is why you see that. The main point is that your `DrawerLayout` should have only one main content `View`; i.e., one non-drawer `View`. You need to put all of the main content inside one `ViewGroup`. For example, you could put the `Toolbar` and the `FrameLayout` both inside a vertical `LinearLayout`, which wouldn't overlap the two.

Comment: Mike M. really thank you so much. I spend whole day to solve this problem. Because of your help and expertise I get the solution. Thank you once again. People like your are really great for help.

Answer (score 0):

I can support you giving you my working code for Android 27.1.1:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
 BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private int mSelectedId;

/**
 * Create Navigation bar and load the main fragment "statistics".
 */

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    loadFragment(new FragmentStatistics());

    BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    mSelectedId = navigation.getSelectedItemId();
}

/**
 * Checks for any event in the Navigation Bar.
 * If the item selected is the same as the actual item
 * Do nothing
 * Else
 * Load new fragment selected.
 */

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    Fragment fragment = null;

    if (mSelectedId != item.getItemId()) {

        mSelectedId = item.getItemId();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.statistics:
                fragment = new FragmentStatistics();
                break;

            case R.id.shops:
                fragment = new FragmentShops();
                break;

          }

    }

    return loadFragment(fragment);
}

private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {

    //switching fragment
    if (fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
 }

 }
```

The rest of your code is exact as mine.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: Maybe I could improve my answer if you show the logcat trace showing what happens when you try to start the new fragment. In my short experience working with fragments showing the code of the main class is not enough to solve the problems.

Comment: 544-942/? D/gralloc_vbox86: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
544-942/? D/gralloc_vbox86: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
544-942/? D/gralloc_vbox86: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
2306-2322/demoapp.com.demoapp E/EGL_emulation: tid 2322: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
2306-2322/demoapp.com.demoapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xd2dd04c0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
2306-2311/demoapp.com.demoapp I/art: